# Algorithm to generate non word keys

Tags: c#, algorithm, passwords

I am on the mission to generate human friendly and memorable short keys, requirements are:

- about 4 to 6 characters long with the Base36 [0-9A-Z]
  case-insensitive charset.
- Lowest percentage of meaningful words coming up, swearing words or not.
- Maximizing the number of keys in range we can use within max 6 characters.
- The list doesn't have to be totally random, it can be sequential.

Is there any nice functions or algorithms out there to do this? Thank you.

Comment: How do you define "human friendly and memorable"?

Comment: @Andrew, as I mentioned, 4-6 chars case-insenstive base36 is the requirement of being 'friendly and memorable' in this case.

Comment: I believe that you want a [perfect hash function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_hash_function).

Comment: `C#` and `java` are two different languages. Don't tag both.

Comment: Please don't spam comment that are useless or not related to question